# using the HomeController for additional actions bad practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

We have an ASP.NET MVC4 Mobile app and right now there are 5 additional actions that can get invoked from the Home page. These actions are pretty simple but it seems wrong to me that they are under the /Home/BrowseMsg, /Home/CompleteMsg etc.similar to how /Home/About and /Home/Contact is under Home. The Views then are also contained in their *.cshtml files under /View/Home/BrowseMsg.cshtml and so on. For About and Contact this seems to make sense but for actions having to do with the domain this just doesn't feel right. I would prefer to have a MsgController or something that has these additional actions. There probably isn't a right or wrong answer to this but maybe I am missing something as to how to apply Conventions over Configurations. I would appreciate anyone's experience in this area to share their ideas about this. I know you can do just about anything that you need by configuration, but does this make sense?
Thanks in Advance for any insights.
regards!

Comment: Normally and as I know it will be good that every model or entity has a controller. so for some actions which have something in common, use a controller. personally I prefer use MsgController instead of using HomeController. Even from the name of controller I can realize it has something to do with message.

Comment: The division is based on business requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path. Usually one controller is supposed to focus on specific kind of functionality. It is accordance with [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which says a class must be having one responsibility (so a class encapsulates bunch of fields, properties and methods etc. related to one specific entity/goal). In similar way, a controller should be responsible for controlling the requests for specific functionality.

It is all about better organization of code which makes it more readable, easy to understand and maintainable. In your case it seems use of specific controllers are needed.

If you have big ASP.NET MVC application, it is advised to use Areas feature and each area is supposed to have code (model, view and controller etc.) related to one modules. For more please have a look on this article: "[Areas in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC)".

Hope it would give you more clarity to move ahead. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Snesh. This is exactly what I was thinking as well - that it is a violation of the SRP. Putting all of these actions in the HomeController seems like temporal cohesion at best. In addition, it also seems like a code smell, Large Class, which is another symptom of violating the SRP. I further don't agree that the rationalization of "simplicity" is an answer to this concern. We could always write all of our code in a single class and justify this as "simple". The other concern is the url - having /Home/ in the url for an action is misleading as well.

Comment: As I think more about this it seems that grouping all of these actions into the HomeController may be more an example of "coincidential" cohesion rather than "temporal".